# Accessing xcode variables in Cordova config

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have an iOS application that has many different configurations all under the same Xcode project. I am using Targets to achieve this. My application utilizes Cordova. I am wondering if it is possible/best way to access Xcode variables within my Cordova config.xml file.

I am hoping to achieve having one shared config file with many targets in Xcode and when I select a target and build and run my variables for that target will be dynamically injected into my config.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create 'Configuration Settings File' (.xcconfig) and configure variables from the info.plist with this pattern $(VARIABLE) and add into the .xcconfig file. This way you'll be able to set “Bundle Identifier”, “Bundle name”, “Bundle version” and other stuff you need to configure.

You may refer guide link to get more info: https://www.appcoda.com/xcconfig-guide/

Hope it helps!